# Convert a one dimensional dataframe into a 3 dimensional for RGB Image

Tags: python, pandas, image, numpy

I have a data frame of 2304 columns , as it is a 48*48 image pixels, when I convert it into one channel using this code

```
x = (df.iloc[:,1:].values).astype('float32')

x = x.reshape(-1,48,48,1)
```

its perfectly output of shape

```
(48*48*1)
```

with generating exact image by this code:

```
plt.imshow(x[0][:,:,0])
```

I want to make it into a 3Dimentional like in three channels. I try to merged the df 3 times and do this `(48*48*3)` it successfully change the df shape but I cannot generate the image again,

Comment: before getting into the question, why would you want to use dataframes for images? why not just use numpy ndarrays instead?

Comment: i feel easy in pandas

Comment: if thats the only reason, i think you may want to take this as a good opportunity to pick up numpy arrays. images go together really well with arrays, and pandas really go together well with tabular data. Apart from being really suboptimal, you'll find pandas may not behave well with images, and most image based libraries work with arrays, (actually, all that i know of work with arrays. its just the right data structure for storing RGB values) and you'd have to convert anyways.

Comment: if you have some idea how to do it in numpy you can tell me, by the way that reshape is basically a numpy function, i Use wrong notation df

Comment: thanks everyone, I am doing more search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you essentially want to convert a single channel image (which should essentially be a greyscale image) into a 3 channel greyscale image, its the same as concatenating the same image array thrice along the last axis. You can use [np.concatenate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html#numpy.concatenate) to achieve the desired result.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros((2304), dtype = np.uint8) #Just a dummy array representing a single pic
single_channel = a.reshape(48, 48, 1)

result = np.concatenate([single_channel,single_channel,single_channel], axis = -1)
print(result.shape) #(48, 48, 3)
```

At this point you should have an array that can be accepted by any image library. Just throwing a sample code to show how you may proceed to create the image from the array.

```
import cv2
cv2.imwrite("hi.jpg", result)
```

As stated earlier, use numpy instead of pandas for image manipulation.

**EDIT**: If you were unfortunately starting with a dataframe in the first place, you can always convert it to a numpy array with an extra dimension representing each image.

```
import pandas as pd
import cv2
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros((2304), dtype = np.uint8) #dummy row

dummy_df = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate([a.reshape(1,-1)]*10)) #dummy df with 10 rows.
print(dummy_df.shape) #(10, 2304) 
arr_images = np.array(dummy_df, dtype = np.uint8)
print(arr_images.shape) #(10, 2304)
multiple_single_channel = arr_images.reshape(-1, 48, 48, 1)
print(multiple_single_channel.shape) #(10, 48, 48, 1)
result = np.concatenate([multiple_single_channel] * 3, axis = -1)
print(result.shape) #(10, 48, 48, 3)

for i,img in enumerate(result):
    print(i)
    cv2.imwrite("{}.jpg".format(i), img)
    #do something with image. you PROBABLY don't want to run this for 35k images though.
```

The bottom line really is that you should not need to use a dataframe, even for multiple images.

Comment: sorry not to mention earlier, convert image into 3channels its not a big deal it can be done by  this backtorgb = cv2.cvtColor(gray,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB) script, why I have dataframe because I have 35k images, so I need to convert them at once

Comment: @KhanHassan Converting a df to a numpy array shouldn't be an issue. how does your dataframe look? is it 35k rows and 2304 columns?

Comment: @KhanHassan That should get you started. numpy arrays can handle multiple images at once without issues as well, its just arrays after all.

Answer (score 0):

1)Dont use pandas

2) you cant transform 1channel image into 3 channels,

3) Dont use float32, images are usually 8bit (np.uint8)

4) use numpy in combination with OpenCV or with Pillow.

5) Dont use matplotlib to generate images. use libraries mentioned in 4.

6) if you have array with shape (x,y,3) there is nothing more simply than generate image with opencv cv2.imshow('image',array)

Comment: sorry not to mention earlier, convert image into 3channels its not a big deal it can be done by this backtorgb = cv2.cvtColor(gray,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB) script, why I have dataframe because I have 35k images, so I need to convert them at once

Comment: Of course image can be given 2 additional channels, but why would you do that? Gray is gray and no matter how many channels you add. Only result is that the image is bigger and slower for processing. Unless you plan to draw on gray image some colors, I would let it be 1 channelled